# Is it possible to get result of an operation Speech to Text Recognition by its ID (Python)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python

I'm trying to get response of successfully executed long_running_recognize request (speech_v1p1beta1) by its ID.
I know how to get this job done from console by using SDK

```
gcloud ml speech operations wait <operation ID>
```

But I can not find any proper way to do this by using Python. All my attempts to solve the problem were with no success so far.
What I'm trying to find out is the way to get a text which is already recognized from a speech by Google Speech to Text API. 
Let's imagine that I've already got the ID of that operation. The recognition was done, API returned its ID. A few days later I am going to run a Python script to process that text. What I want is to get the text from API directly within my Python code, without sending request via console.

Something like that

```
operation_ID = 123456788923 #ID of successfully done recognition
text_raw = operations.get(operation_ID)# just an example, it does not work this way
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different ways:

The first one is using the Python Client for Cloud Speech API [1], in [2] and if you scroll down you'll find a first example of an implementation of long_running_recognize using this Python Library, in [3] you have another example. Another example is [4] but here they use a simple recognize. I just share it so you have more examples, use the one that works better for you.

I don't know if this is exactly what you need but I hope you'll find the solution here. Also notice that this Client Library is in beta feature currently [5], I haven't tried but it should work.

The second one is using the python subprocess module to call specific bash commands, in [4] you have the official documentation. I use this trick sometimes when something works on a terminal and I don't find a proper implementation in python.

[1] https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/index.html

[2] https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/gapic/v1p1beta1/api.html

[3] https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/index.html#asynchronous-recognition

[4] https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#make_an_audio_transcription_request

[5] https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/release-notes#June_18_2019

[6] https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thank you for your willing to help and links you provide with. But none of them contains description of a function to get a result of speech recognition later on by sending a request to API within Python code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I completely misunderstood you. I focused on understand the python library for myself and at the end I lost the root issue...

Does it [1] points what you mean?, I think you can access everything via http request.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/operations